# How to get all links and their Wikidata IDs for a Wikipedia page?

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata-api

(When) will the following be possible?

- get the list of all links on a Wikipedia page with their respective Wikidata IDs in a single query/API call.
- receive additional information of the respective Wikidata items like a property value with the query.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood, yes, it is question, but GautamSavaliya was deleted it (check history).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get all Wikipedia page links you have to use [Wikipedia API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?), and to get all Wikidata item properties you need [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?), so it is not possible to create one query with two requests to both APIs. But! The first part of your question is already possible. And about the second... you didn't say anything for this what information you need from Wikidata.

You can get Wikidata IDs and a lot of other information for all Wikipedia page links, like coordinates, refs, internal and external links, images, text content, contributors, history, page rights, categories, templates etc... To do this we can use only Wikipedia API because our entry point is the Wikipedia page, plus **generator** feature of the API.

For example, this is how to get Wikidata ID, short intro text and the main image for first 20 interwiki links on [Dolphin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin) Wikipedia page:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=links&format=xml&redirects=1&titles=Dolphin&prop=pageprops|extracts|pageimages&gpllimit=20&ppprop=wikibase_item&exintro=1&exlimit=20&piprop=name&pilimit=20
```

**Main [query](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) parameters:**

- `action=query&format=xml&redirects=1&titles=Dolphin`
- `generator=links` - to get all page [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Blinks) (works together with `gpllimit=20`)
- `prop=pageprops|extracts|pageimages` - what to get from the links

**Properties:**

- [pageprops](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bpageprops) - to get Wikidata ID (works with `ppprop=wikibase_item`)
- [extracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts) - to get first text lines from that page (works with `exintro=1` and `exlimit=20`)
- [pageimages](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bpageimages) - to get main image (works with `piprop=name` and `pilimit=20`)

In the same way you can get and another information listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) in parameter `prop`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible with a query modification to receive a wikidata property in addition to the the already queried information, e.g. `instance of` (so, again, everything in a single query)?

Comment: These are two different APIs corresponding for two different databases. The interwiki links are in the Wikipedia article and can't be accessed by Wikidata API because there isn't information for them in Wikidata. Also, the properties are located in Wikidata and can't be accessed by Wikipedia API